# Table caption alignment

Tags: tables, captions

I have a table like this:
[image]

How can I align Caption with left of table not paper?!

And I want to stretch the table a little.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \caption{Dimensions of simulated tissue containing a malignant tumor, all dimensions are in millimeters}
 \label{tabdimension}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
X & Y & Z & D& R \\
\hline
120 & 60 & 25 & 12 &10 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `threeparttable`. In addition, part of the caption can go at the bottom of the table, as a `tablenote`. Using the rule of `booktabs` wil add some vertical padding around the rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable, booktabs,  caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Dimensions of simulated tissue containing a malignant tumor}
    \label{tabdimension}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      \toprule
      X   & Y  & Z  & D  & R  \\
      \midrule
      120 & 60 & 25 & 12 & 10 \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
      \footnotesize
      \item All dimensions are in mm
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer to have a two-line caption, you can set the caption width with `\captionsetup`, but can't use `threeparttable` In this case, a work around consists in adding a new row to the table, with this code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{font=footnotesize, width= 47mm}
    \caption{Dimensions of simulated tissue containing a malignant tumor}
    \label{tabdimension}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      \toprule
      X   & Y  & Z  & D  & R  \\
      \midrule
      120 & 60 & 25 & 12 & 10 \\
      \bottomrule
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize All dimensions are in mm}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. how can i increase the table width a little?

Comment: The table width depends on the table contents.   You can choose a fixed width, while keeping the cell contents centred with `\begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{\centering p{some width}}}`. The specifier `p` may be replaced with  m` or `b`, depending on the vertical alignment inside cells. You also may choose the overall width of the table with the `\tabularx` environment.